# How Do I Change What the UIPickerView Says?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uipickerview

I am developing an app that uses the PickerView, but I can't figure out how to change what it says. Currently it just says "Cupertino, Sunnyvale, etc" and it won't go up or down. And when I do the simulator, it just shows up as a blue rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate to supply the data and configure the appearance of the picker view. The default text values are just what are shown in Interface Builder - once wired-up to a datasource/delegate the view should show your information when in the simulator.

Comment: You write a class that conforms to those two protocols.